# Cannot change parent's state from child component in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a simple chat app, but a new comment posted from the input field in the child component is not displayed.
--Parent component--

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      comments: [],
      currentUser: { displayName: "user3", uid: 3 }
    };
  }

  addComment = comment => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      comments: prevState.comments.push(comment);
    });

    console.log("this.state");
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    const { comments, currentUser } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {comments.map(comment => (
          <div className="line__left" key={comment.createdAt}>
            <figure>
              <i className="fas fa-user fa-4x" />
            </figure>
            <div className="line__left-text">
              <div className="name">{comment.createdBy.displayName}</div>
              <div className="text">{comment.text}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}

        <ChatInputBox addComment={this.addComment} currentUser={currentUser} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

--Child component--

```
class ChatInputBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: "",
      currentUser: this.props.currentUser
    };
  }
  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  };
  handleClickPost = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let comment = {
      createdAt: new Date().getTime(),
      createdBy: this.state.currentUser,
      text: this.state.text
    };
    this.props.addComment(comment);
    this.setState({ text: "" });
  };

  render() {
    const { text } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="ChatInputBox">
        ChatBox
        <textarea onChange={this.handleChange} value={text} />
        <button onClick={this.handleClickPost}>Post</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

After I populate the text area and click the button, parent's state seems to be updated, but new comment is not shown.How can I show it?

Comment: Here is the code sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/v0m7p2v873

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code

```
  addComment = comment => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      comments: prevState.comments.push(comment);
    });

    console.log("this.state");
    console.log(this.state);
  };
```

to

```
  addComment = comment => {
    const { comments } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      comments: comments.concat(comment)
    });
  };
```

when you are using `setState()`, using `concat` instead of `push` since it maintains your array's immutability.

Comment: There is also a OP misunderstanding of the execution of setState that, being async, has to be checked (console.log()) in its callback, and not outside the setState method

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini right, but logging is not necessary for fixing this issue, so I wiped that out.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. It works! I'm also happy to understand that I should use callback if I need to log the state.